# TypeError: string indices must be integers JSON

Tags: python, json, webhooks

I am struggling with filtering json data from a webhook. I am not too sure what is incorrect/wrong here:

```
headers = {
    'client-id': 'my twitch client id',
    'Authorization': 'my twitch oauth key',
}

params = (
    ('query', x),
)

response = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels', headers=headers, params=params)

final = response.text["is_live"]

print(final)
```

It gives me the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

However, I am unsure how I would turn the json data from the webhook into an interger?

EDIT: Query 'x' is retrieved from my MongoDB and works fine.

response.text returns:

```
{"data":[{"broadcaster_language":"en","display_name":"foxygaming09","game_id":"32982","id":"87678172","is_live":false,"tag_ids":[],"thumbnail_url":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures"}]
```

Comment: Use `response.json` instead of `response.text`

Comment: ```TypeError: json() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: _I am insure how I would turn the json data from the webhook into an integer_ Are you sure that the issue is due to the fact that the request data is not an int?

Comment: @AMC, the format/type of the data seems fine. I just don't know how I would filter a certain part of it. Even if it isn't an int, is there a way to work around this?

Comment: @Pois I’m talking about the TypeError you shared above.

Comment: @AMC The type error seems to be consistent, even when I change the link to another request. (interger).

Comment: @Pois I’m not sure I understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: @AMC I changed the GET request URL to a source that I know sends back JSON as an integer, and the error is still there.

Comment: Can you print out `response.json()` or  `response.text` for everyone to see?

Comment: @Pois _sends back JSON as an integer_ JSON as an integer?

Comment: From your code, there is no way to know what you put in your `headers` and `params`, it is difficult to help you solve the problem

Comment: Hi, apologies for that. I will edit it now to show you.

Comment: @dudulu I’m not sure I agree, I don’t think we need to know more about the request itself. It would be useful if OP shared the complete error message, though.

Comment: First of all `response.text["is_live"]` is definitely wrong, it should be `response.json()["is_live"]`

Comment: @AMC Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\get mongodb collections.py", line 25, in <module>
    final = (response.text["is_live"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Pois Be careful! Are you sure that the result of `response.text` you shared is correct/accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, please use.

What is returned is JSON.

Should use `.json()`.

And perform data manipulation.

```
final = response.json()
```

`final = {"data":[{"broadcaster_language":"en","display_name":"","game_id":"","id":"","is_live":false,"tag_ids":[],"thumbnail_url":""}]`

```
print(final['data'][0]['is_live'])
```

output

```
false
```

I can do it unless the response.text you provide is incorrect.

Comment: hi, this produces a syntax error on the apostrophes bordering data.

Comment: Ok. That might be because I don’t understand your English well, I thought you just wanted to get the value of `['is_live']`.

Comment: yes I only wish to get the value of it's live.

Comment: But a syntax error pops up when using the above code specified by you.

Comment: `final = {"data":[{"broadcaster_language":"en","display_name":"","game_id":"","id":"","is_live":false,"tag_ids":[],"thumbnail_url":""}] `   `print(final'data'][0]['is_live'])`  output -> false